# Dovecot on CentOS 6 doesn't work after update

Tags: linux, centos, sendmail, dovecot

I recently updated CentOS to version 6.8 (Final). I'm not sure if then dovecot stopped working or a bit later. I see **nothing** in `secure` log on **correct password** and "failure" on wrong password. I never touched /etc/pam.d - should be OS default. It worked before. I have no idea why it's not working now.

I'm using dovecot + sendmail. Sendmail is authenticating via sasl->PAM and it's working fine.

I tried passdb `shadow` to see what's wrong, but no success.

This may be coincidence, but for some reason  md check was forced (using raid 1 on all partitions)

**Update:** After raid check finished dmesg shows this.

```
auth[14058]: segfault at 9c ip 000000000040f8e0 sp 00007ffe99788070 error 4 in auth[400000+37000]
auth[14133]: segfault at 8c ip 000000000040f8e0 sp 00007ffc7ec2ee60 error 4 in auth[400000+37000]
```

Before dmesg was full of these messages: "delaying data-check of md4 until md3 has finished", so I couldn't see the segfault...

Configuration:

```
# dovecot -n
# 2.0.9: /etc/dovecot/dovecot.conf
# OS: Linux 2.6.32-642.1.1.el6.centos.plus.x86_64 x86_64 CentOS release 6.8 (Final)
auth_debug = yes
auth_gssapi_hostname = $ALL
auth_verbose = yes
log_path = /var/log/dovecot.log
mail_debug = yes
mail_location = mbox:~/mail:INBOX=/var/spool/mail/%u
mbox_write_locks = fcntl
passdb {
  args = failure_show_msg=yes dovecot
  driver = pam
}
passdb {
  driver = shadow
}
protocols = imap pop3
service auth-worker {
  user = root
}
service auth {
  user = root
}
ssl_cert = </etc/pki/dovecot/certs/dovecot.pem
ssl_key = </etc/pki/dovecot/private/dovecot.pem
userdb {
  driver = passwd
}
verbose_proctitle = yes
```

dovecot log:

```
Jul 18 02:18:12 auth: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib64/dovecot/auth
Jul 18 02:18:12 auth: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/auth/libauthdb_ldap.so
Jul 18 02:18:12 auth: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/auth/libdriver_sqlite.so
Jul 18 02:18:12 auth: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/auth/libmech_gssapi.so
Jul 18 02:18:12 auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=24897)
Jul 18 02:18:16 auth: Debug: client in: AUTH    1       PLAIN   service=imap    secured lip=5.9.143.206 rip=176.12.6.242        lport=143       rport=64099
Jul 18 02:18:16 auth: Debug: client out: CONT   1
Jul 18 02:18:16 auth: Debug: client in: CONT<hidden>
Jul 18 02:18:16 auth: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib64/dovecot/auth
Jul 18 02:18:16 auth: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/auth/libauthdb_ldap.so
Jul 18 02:18:16 auth: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/auth/libdriver_sqlite.so
Jul 18 02:18:16 auth: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/auth/libmech_gssapi.so
Jul 18 02:18:16 auth: Debug: pam(npelov,176.12.6.242): lookup service=dovecot
Jul 18 02:18:16 auth: Debug: pam(npelov,176.12.6.242): #1/1 style=1 msg=Password:
Jul 18 02:18:19 auth: Info: pam(npelov,176.12.6.242): pam_authenticate() failed: Authentication failure (password mismatch?)
Jul 18 02:18:19 master: Error: service(auth): child 24898 killed with signal 11 (core dumps disabled)
Jul 18 02:18:19 auth: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib64/dovecot/auth
Jul 18 02:18:19 auth: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/auth/libauthdb_ldap.so
Jul 18 02:18:19 auth: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/auth/libdriver_sqlite.so
Jul 18 02:18:19 auth: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/auth/libmech_gssapi.so
Jul 18 02:18:19 auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=24897)
Jul 18 02:18:19 auth: Debug: client in: AUTH    2       PLAIN   service=imap    secured lip=5.9.143.206 rip=176.12.6.242        lport=143       rport=64099     resp=<hidden>
Jul 18 02:18:19 auth: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib64/dovecot/auth
Jul 18 02:18:19 auth: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/auth/libauthdb_ldap.so
Jul 18 02:18:19 auth: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/auth/libdriver_sqlite.so
Jul 18 02:18:19 auth: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/auth/libmech_gssapi.so
Jul 18 02:18:19 auth: Debug: pam(npelov,176.12.6.242): lookup service=dovecot
Jul 18 02:18:19 auth: Debug: pam(npelov,176.12.6.242): #1/1 style=1 msg=Password:
Jul 18 02:18:20 auth: Info: pam(npelov,176.12.6.242): pam_authenticate() failed: Authentication failure (password mismatch?)
Jul 18 02:18:20 master: Error: service(auth): child 25050 killed with signal 11 (core dumps disabled)
Jul 18 02:18:24 auth: Debug: Loading modules from directory: /usr/lib64/dovecot/auth
Jul 18 02:18:24 auth: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/auth/libauthdb_ldap.so
Jul 18 02:18:24 auth: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/auth/libdriver_sqlite.so
Jul 18 02:18:24 auth: Debug: Module loaded: /usr/lib64/dovecot/auth/libmech_gssapi.so
Jul 18 02:18:24 auth: Debug: auth client connected (pid=24897)
```

manual test:

```
# openssl s_client -connect <host>:993
CONNECTED(00000003)
..............................................
..............................................
..............................................
a1 LOGIN npelov validpassword
a1 NO [UNAVAILABLE] Temporary authentication failure.
* OK Waiting for authentication process to respond..
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you've suffered some sort of soft disk failure that has triggered a check/rebuild of the disks and that failure corrupted part of the dovecot installation.

I would also:

- If possible, check the S.M.A.R.T. performance/health counters for your disks, there might be a catastrophic hardware failure imminent
- Verify the files of other packages using `rpm -Va`; any binary files which have either an incorrect size or a bad checksum are possibly also corrupted

Comment: How do I interpret output of rpm -Va: ".M....G.." and "S.5....T.", and "....L.G.."? first is a dir /usr/lib64/bind, second is a lot of config files, including dovecot ones, third is some bind config files. I don't think I see any binaries though.

Comment: They're listed in the `rpm(8)` manpage; from left to right it's (S)ize, (M)ode, MD(5), (D)evice node mismatch, read(L)ink mismatch, (U)ser, (G)roup and modification (T)ime. Anything with a 'c' in the second column indicates a file marked by a package as a configuration file and so are quite normal.

Comment: I'll accept this as an answer because it would have shown the problem right away.

Answer (score 0):

Reinstalling dovecot packet fixed the problem:

```
# yum reinstall dovecot
# service dovecot restart
```

**Update:**
smart doesn't report any error.